# Open file with Standard editor and jump to a specific line

Tags: c++, qt, shellexecute

I'm programming a little tool to handle XML files. It is written in C++ with Qt.

To open such files with an Editor I used:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(file.xml))
```

The next step was to open that XML file and jump to a specific line. I tried to use `ShellExecute`:

```
ShellExecute (NULL, "open", "Notepad.exe", "path.xml -l 200", NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

However, it didn't work. The line above opens the file `path.xml`, but not at line 200. I tried the same with `VIM` instead of Notepad, with the same result. Where is my error?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using "edit" instead of "open"?

Comment: Why do you expect, that "-l 200" means "open at line 200"? As I know, there are only four command line parameters of Notepad: /A, /W, /P and /PT (and no one of them helps to move cursor to specified line). So, first of all, you need to find editor, which support parameter "-l" or other parameter for opening on specified line.

Comment: Try to use these parameters for opening by VIM: "+200 path.xml".

Comment: Yes. Is there an Editor supports any kind of line parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in the following way (Windows):

```
QProcess proc;
proc.startDetached("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\Notepad++",
                    QStringList() << "file.xml" << "-n 2000");
```

The code above opens an instance of Notepad++ application, loads file.xml file and scrolls to the line 2000 ([-n command line switch](http://npp-wiki.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Command_Line_Switches#Alphabetical_list_of_supported_switches)) of the opened file.

Comment: @wattele, yeah, the same approach can work with any text editor that supports such command line arguments.